# Inconsistent Cognos errors

Tags: networking, cognos, gateway, cognos-10

I am trying to do a couple of things within Cognos:

1. Load Framework Manager and view/modify SQL behind existing models and create new models
2. Modify existing reports through Report Studio via Cognos Connection

I was given an account on the Cognos application server and I installed Framework Manager.  I was given the gateway URL and dispatcher URL from the System Admin and then transferred all of the project files to the server so that I could load the project in question.  I'm able to open the .cpf file; however, when going into any models, I get the error:

```
Unable to access service at URL: 

https://xxx.cognos.xxx.xxx:443/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognos.cgi?b_action=xts.run&m=portal/close.xts

Please check that your gateway URI information is configured correctly and that the service is available.

For further information please contact your service administrator.
```

I then contacted the system admin and he indicated that the URL was correct.

Furthermore, now when I try to access Cognos Connection (which worked fine last week), I receive the error:

```
CM-REQ-4159 

 Content Manager returned an error in the response header. The error "cmAuthenticateFailed CM-CAM-4005 Unable to authenticate. Check your security directory server connection and confirm the credentials entered at login." can be found in the response SOAP header.
```

The odd thing is, another member of my team receives this error:

```
AAA-AUT-0016:
    https://xxx.cognos.xxx.xxx/ps/images/space.gif
    https://xxx.cognos.xxx.xxx/ps/images/space.gif
    https://xxx.cognos.xxx.xxx/ps/portal/images/msg_error.gif
    The function call to 'Method.invoke(cmServiceInstance, queryRequest)' failed.
    https://xxx.cognos.xxx.xxx/ps/images/space.gif



DetailsExpand:
    CM-SYS-5192 An error occurred with Content Manager.
```

I've done some research (I'm not really familiar with Cognos or even networking) and found that these errors (the ones that I receive) are usually received when trying to run a single report; however, I can't even access FM models or Cognos Connection in general.  I also don't understand how we can receive 2 different errors when accessing the same URLs from the same network.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  We are using Cognos 10.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21624136
One possible reason is that the user does not have the required "Import relational metadata" capability.

Or maybe it is something to do with the registry
Note: Make sure you backup the registry before making any changes.
see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22015730

1. Open cmd and type "regedit".
2. Navigate to [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl.
3. Right click "BMT.exe" = dword:00002af9.
4. Delete.
5. Re-launch Framework Manager.